# Cannot specify a column width on data type text

Tags: sql-server-2008

My table has a error called

> Msg 2716, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column, parameter, or variable #8:
>   Cannot specify a column width on data type text.

and I dont see the problems.

**heres the query:**

```
create table tblAdd (
OfficeType nchar not null, 
OfficeName varchar (24) not null,
AssetClassification varchar (24) not null,
AssetSubClass varchar(24) not null, 
UACSObjectCode int primary key not null,
AssetItem varchar (24) not null,
Manufacturer varchar(24) not null,
Model text (24) not null, 
SerialNumber text (24) not null,
Specification text (24) not null, 
PropertyNumber text (24) not null,
CurrentCondition text (24) not null,
SourceOfFund varchar (24) not null, 
CostOfAcquisition money not null,
DateIfAcquisition date not null,
EstimatedTotalLifeYears int not null, 
NameOfAccountableOffice varchar (24) not null,
AssetLocation varchar (24) not null,
Remarks text (24) not null
```

)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked what **text** datatype is? 
It is a legacy CLOB field that allows 2GB of data.

I presume you want **varchar(max)** which replaces text since SQL Server 2005

In other comments

- "OfficeType nchar" will be one character by default.
- Are all your filed meant to be varchar(24)?

Comment: now i understand, the text datatype has a default of max length hahaha thanks :*